# Setting up a network between linux VirtualBox and Windows 7

Tags: windows, linux, networking, virtualbox

I have a Windows 7 machine with an installation of Linux in VirtualBox. I need to setup a network connection between the two.

Are there some tutorials on how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this manual:
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

It is a dedicated manual written by VirtualBox, and should explain the Virtual Networking functionality to you clearly.